# Use an Angular directive to generate html from an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use an Angular directive to create a form where the user can specify the number of children and, for each child, an edit box appears allowing the childs date of birth to be entered.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="KidCtrl">
    <form>
    How many children:<input ng-model="numChildren" ng-change="onChange()"/><br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in children">
            <child-dob></child-dob>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function KidCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.numChildren = 2
  $scope.children = [{dob: "1/1/90"}, {dob: "1/1/95"}];
  $scope.onChange = function () {
    $scope.children.length = $scope.numChildren;
  }
}

app.directive('childDob', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'Child {{$index+1}} - date of birth: <input ng-model="child.dob" required/>'
    };
  });
```

And here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byj3fhLL/)

The problem is that it's just not working.
If I enter 1 in the numChildren field then it shows 1 bullet point for the list element but it doesn't show any of the HTML.
If I enter 2 in the numChildren field then it doesn't show any list elements.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that the directive `childDOB` is never rendered. Even though your controller works because 1.2.x version of angular has global controller discover on. It will look for any public constructors in the global scope to match the controller name in the ng-controller directive. It does not happen for directive. So the absence of `ng-app="appname"` there is no way the directive gets rendered. So add the appname `ng-app="myApp"` and see it working. It is also a good practice not to pollute global scope and register controller properly with `controller()` constructor. (Global look up has anyways been deprecated as of 1.3.x and can only be turned off at global level.)

You would also need to add `track by` in ng-repeat due to the repeater that can occur due to increasing the length of the array based on textbox value. It can result in multiple array values to be undefined resulting in duplicate. SO:-

```
 ng-repeat="child in children track by $index"
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wpL8bfh/)**

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="KidCtrl">
        <form>How many children:
            <input ng-model="numChildren" ng-change="onChange()" />
            <br/>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="child in children track by $index">{{$index}}
                    <child-dob></child-dob>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('KidCtrl', KidCtrl);

    KidCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function KidCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.numChildren = 2
        $scope.children = [{
            dob: "1/1/1990"
        }, {
            dob: "1/1/1995"
        }];
        $scope.onChange = function () {
            $scope.children.length = $scope.numChildren;
        }
    }

    app.directive('childDob', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: 'Child {{$index+1}} - date of birth: <input ng-model="child.dob" required/>'
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a million - my problem just went away and I learned useful things in the process!